# Is there a command line tool to insert line breaks into a long string?

Tags: text-processing

Given a long string that needs to be displayed with limited text-width, is there a command line tool in *nix that converts the single-line string to a multi-line string with each line being no longer than a given text-width?

For example, given the following string

```
$ MYSTRING="Call me Ishmael. Some years ago - never mind how long precisely - having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world."
```

I would like to format somewhat like this:

```
$ echo $MYSTRING | special-format-command --width=30
Call me Ishmael. Some years ag
o - never mind how long precis
ely - having little or no mone
y in my purse, and nothing par
ticular to interest me on shor
e, I thought I would sail abou
t a little and see the watery 
part of the world.
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You might try the `fold` command:

```
echo "$MYSTRING" | fold -w 30
```

Comment: +1, but perhaps better written as `echo $MYSTRING | fold -w 30`, since the `-30` syntax doesn't appear in the [fold manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fold)?

Comment: For posterity, there is also `fmt`. The difference between `fold` and `fmt` is that `fold` will wrap at the fixed width, even splitting words and may begin lines with blanks. While `fmt` will wrap near or under the width, it will not split words, lines will not begin with blanks and short lines may be joined.

Comment: `fold` appears to have similar behavior to `fmt` when the `-s` option is used.

Comment: funny, i used -w option but it split it by char.

Answer (score 7):

The entire purpose of `fmt` (part of GNU coreutils, and IIRC other versions were included with non-GNU *nixes, so is almost certain to be already installed) is to reformat paragraphs.

However, there is an even better tool called `par` (for paragraph reformatter).  It can do everything that `fmt` can do, but with a lot more options to control the exact output format.

One of the many really nice things about `par` is that it is very smart about handling quoting in emails (even multiple levels of quoting) - very useful...I have my .vimrc set up so that hitting F5 sends the current paragraph through par.

If it's not packaged for your distro (it is for debian and derivatives, probably others too), par can be found at http://www.nicemice.net/par/

Comment: By "non-GNU *nixes", do you mean the "real" (not "Unix-like") Unixes? (Otherwise cool tool, it seems.)

Comment: i mean now-obsolete proprietary junk *nixes.

Comment: That's what I thought, but why are you then using the asterisk? I thought that was to get around having to type "Unix-like" all the time (for Linux etc.). (I'm not bugging you over a detail - or well, I am - but I really want to know, I'm not bugging you for the sake of it.)

Comment: `*nix` is just a way of saying "generic unix or unix-like systems" - it dates from a time when the word Unix was a proprietary trademark of AT&T

Answer (score 6):

Here's a method using `sed`:

```
sed 's/.\{30\}/&\
/g'
```

Comment: But what does it mean?

Comment: @Richard Replace 30 of any character except newline (`.\{30\}`), with the same string (`&`), followed by a newline.

Answer (score 3):

`fold -s` is the shortest, best answer to your question.

However, as good as those one-purpose tools are in some cases, in general, you should have your editor do this.

In Emacs, you could tweak this anyway you'd like. As for me, I use `visual-line-mode` (shows up as a `Wrap` minor mode in the mode line) because in the general case, I don't want line breaks anywhere else than at the end of paragraphs.

I thought I'd tell the way I do it. It is not "the" way, but it is one way; as I mention the functions and variables, **your** way is to put them together and automatize them to make them work for you. (This is Emacs, but for any sufficiently advanced editor, a similar post could be written.)

I said I have the lines visually wrapped when I type, and never break them manually. As always, there are exceptions: for example, GNUS won't send posts to Usenet with lines beyond a certain width (in characters). So, then I use `M-q`. In Emacs, `M-q` runs the command `fill-paragraph`. The variable `fill-column` controls the width for filling. As an example, if I write this (on a single line)

```
This is a lot of text being written right now. The purpose is to overflow the line so I have have to line break it with M-q.
```

and then use M-q, I get

```
This is a lot of text being written right now. The purpose is to
overflow the line so I have have to line break it with M-q.
```

With `justify-current-line` (twice as two lines), you get

```
This  is a lot  of text  being written  right now.  The purpose  is to
overflow  the  line  so  I  have  have to  line  break  it  with  M-q.
```

But, I've found that people seldom use monospace fonts to view things, so it didn't make much sense using it (apart for my own viewing pleasure). If you like it, you could tweak `fill-paragraph` to fill **and** justify at the same time. You could also have Emacs do this for you, always, as you type: `auto-fill-mode`. (I found that stressful, but that's me.)

This may seem like a lot of work, and it is; but once you're done (with this and 1000 other things) you can really enjoy working with the tools behaving precisely as you like them to.